# web services - userGroup.asmx

Tags: web-services

_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx

1. I downloaded this http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com to test the web services.
2. I tested userprofileservice.asmx and tested hand full of methods and it returns expected result.
3. I test UserGroup.asmx , tested GetGroupCollectionFromUser and put the user (domain\mSmith) and it returned data but group names are nulled
4. so I tested another method for the same endpoint. GetuserCollectionFromGroup and this time I put in group (man made created group) and I get error. But I put Approvers or Designers for the group I get xml with users in it.

I do have anyone can see the group checked at the group setting level. Anything else I am missing. I am on this all day (since 6am) and still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Laura: I had a very similar situation and after jacking with it for 4 weeks I decided to use workflow to update certain dates based on user approval.